# Strange behavior in Python 3 using the sys module

Tags: python, python-3.x

While I was trying some stuffs in my Python 3 interpreter (Python 3.4.2, installed via brew), I encountered some weird outputs I didn't expected:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.write("foo")
foo3
>>> sys.stderr.write("bar")
3
bar
```

After experimenting with different strings, I think the number is the length of the inputs I pass.

I've tried this in Python 2.7.8 (gives no numbers in the outputs) and Python 3.4.2 created by `virtualenv` (gives the same result)

Is the output supposed to be like this?

Comment: I believe it is expected behaviour. The number is printed only because you are in python REPL. There won't be any numbers if you run this code as script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right that it's the length. In Python 2, the `File.write()` method returned `None`. When the move was made to Python 3, the return value changed to be the number of characters written.

The reason you're getting the different output from `stdout` and `stderr` will probably have to do with the order in which things show up on the file handles.

For `stdout`, `write` outputs `"foo"` then the REPL loop (in the grand tradition of PIN numbers and ATM machines) outputs the count to the same stream.

For `stderr`, it's likely that the REPL loop outputs standard output first (the length) then the content of standard error.

Or, it may be totally non-deterministic, it's probably not something you should rely on, especially as the REPL loop doesn't really exist except in the interactive mode of the interpreter.

Comment: `stderr` and `stdout` are line buffered; so writing a newline to `stdout` flushed it. But `stderr` wasn't flushed, so you don't see the `bar` in your terminal until it is also explicitly flushed *after the code runs*, which is why it is printed late. If you add a newline to the data written, `bar` appears before the `4`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Just saw this, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 4):

In the python interpreter, when you print something, it shows you the result on stdout and stderr.

I tested it out in my python 3.4. Here is what I think is happening

```
sys.std.write("foo") = > foo3
```

Interpreter writes "foo" to stdout. The interpreter then prints the result of the sys.stdout.write method, which is 3. The end result is foo3. Try sys.stdout.write("foo\n\n"). And this might help you see.

```
sys.stderr.write("bar") => 
3
bar
```

The err stream is not as fast as the stdout. The 3 result from the write shows up first with a new line character. The bar is printed after.

Comment: This has nothing to do with how fast `stderr` is. It is no slower or faster. Both `stdout` and `stderr` are *line buffered* which means they autoflush when a newline is written. No newline is being written here, but the REPL does write out the bytes written count with a newline. So `sys.stdout` is flushed by the newline written by the REPL, but `sys.stderr` never sees a newline. After the code ran, Python explicitly flushes `sys.stderr` anyway, so only the does the message show up in your terminal.

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour is normal. This happens because `sys.stdout.write()` returns the length of the text. Try this code again in a python file. you see, this doesn't happen anymore. This "weird stuff" happens because python automatically prints the return value in the REPL.

```py
'text'
# 'text'
```

if you do this in a python file, there will be no result.
you can prevent this by stopping the return such as this:

```py
_=sys.stdout.write('text')
# text
```

or doing this:

```py
def noreturn(value):
   pass

noreturn(sys.stdout.write('text'))
# text
```